# Prove that a language A is c.e. iff it is the range of a partially computable function

Tags: functions, logic, computability, partial-functions

I am having trouble in formally proving this statement. I looked online and most proofs just mention that it is the part of the definition of c.e (computably enumerable) language.

Comment: To do this you have to take advantage of how $\mathbb N^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$, that is you can enumerate all pairs of natural numbers $(x, y)$.  The $x$ then is the input to your partial function, the $y$ then is the number of steps for which you have run the partial function.  Add some "blah blah blah" to handle repeated values from the range if necessary.

Comment: If you can add an answer, I can accept it : ) Please be more detailed if possible

Comment: This question is missing some key information. One issue is that, if this is not your definition of a c.e. function, then you should state the definition you *are* using in the question.  You should also give a sense of what attempts you have made to prove this alternative characterization from the definition that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're using as your definition of a set being computably enumerable that there is a computable procedure for listing the elements of the set. In this case, the direction $A$ is computably enumerable implies that $A$ is the range of a partial computable function is pretty easy: just define a function $f$ by $f(n)=$ the $n^{th}$ element in the listing of the elements of $A$. Then $f$ is in fact total computable, since to compute $f(n)$ for any $n$ you just run the computable procedure to list the elements of $A$ until $n$ elements have been listed and then just output the $n^{th}$ one.

In the other direction, if $A$ is the range of some partial computable function $f$, then you need to come up with a computable procedure for listing the values of $f(n)$ for all $n$ such that $f(n)$ halts. So e.g. your procedure could start by running the computation $f(0)$ for 1 step, then running $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ both for 2 steps, and so forth, and whenever any of the computations halt outputting the value you get. In this way, you'll eventually list all of the values in the range of $f$, hence all of the elements of $A$.